# Preserve or save default values explicitly in RAD Studio IDE

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm following the example to load a custom font (Segoe UI) in an Android app:

[True Type Font Iconography for Android and iOS Apps](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/true-type-font-iconography-for-android-and-ios-apps)

My problem is that the IDE (RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin) does not save default values to FMX files (the form files). At design time, the default font seems to already be "Segoe UI", so the IDE shows only `(Default)` in the Object Inspector, and so does not store that value to the FMX form file. **BUT**, the default font in Android is "Roboto", not "Segoe UI", and the application indeed uses "Roboto" as the default font at runtime.

So, default values in the object Inspector are not preserved for different target platforms. This is very annoying!

Is this a (logical) bug in the IDE? How can I disable this IDE feature, or explicitly set a value at **design time** (which is accidentally also the default value at design time in the IDE under Windows) and preserve it for the target platform (in this case Android)?

I tried to go into text mode for the FMX form file and set the value manually, but when switching back to design mode, the IDE changes the value in the Object Inspector back to `(Default)` again, and when going back to text-mode again, that line has been removed. I want/need to set it at design time, not runtime, but I can't make it.

I also need such default values for other properties, not only the font.

Comment: I'm not hoping it, I'm using it as a custom font, like I wrote in my second sentence.

Comment: If you tell me how to load custom fonts an Android with FMX at runtime, than I would be really happy. The reason I find it useful to do at design time is, because I can see and test it instantly before compiling for my device.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about setting properties in the object inspector. One of it is the `font family`. I know how to use custom fonts on Android with FMX and I'm setting the `font family` property explicitly to `Segoe UI`. But when I do so, the IDE discards my value and instead sets it to `(Default)` (it simply removes my explicit setting). But Android's standard font is `Roboto`, so thanks to this stupid IDE, I'm not able to set the font `Segoe UI` at design time for Android. It seems I can set it only at runtime - and I don't know how to set it at runtime with the tutorial I linked above.

Comment: I think you really don't understand what I'm writing. I'm not using VLC or Windows. I made my statement quite clear. Please read it again and reproduce what I have written if you don't know the behaviour of the IDE that I'm describing.

Comment: If someone downvotes my question, then please write a comment to let me know what I have done wrong and how I can improve (because I want and will improve). Otherwise please don't downvote - especially not if you do it because you don't like my question for whatever reason. I tried to be as specific as I could. If someone needs more info from me, please ask.

Comment: "*It seems I can set it only at runtime - and I don't know how to set it at runtime with the tutorial I linked above*" - what *specifically* is preventing you from setting the font in code at runtime? The tutorial in question **shows you how to set the font in code at runtime**, so what exactly do you not understand about what it shows you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code is executed in `procedure TAndroidFontGlyphManager.LoadResource;`, which seems to be executed before `onCreate` is triggered (except I missed something) or any other event. Changing the property `Font.Family` at runtime, does not trigger this procedure either. I kindly asked people here to reproduce it or simply give a working code snippet, multiple times, but nope. Thank you for you answer, Remy. But I flagged my question and my account for deletion, since it's out of control and nobody seems to understand what I write or I'm too dumb to understand everyone else...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can see it yourself. Deletion was declined, but please at least close this entirely out of control question. It's my question and it's fine and good if it get's finally closed. I have requested an account deletion for my profile, so I won't read here anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I still do not see a problem here. You can have the GlyphManager load the desired font at app startup so the font is ready for use before any Forms are streamed in from their FMX files. After a Form has finished streaming its FMX file, you can assign that font to the Form's controls as needed, if the FMX file did not already handle that for you. So I still don't see what is blocking you from using custom fonts at runtime, even if it takes a few steps to accomplish.

Comment: the problem is it violates principle of least surprise for the author of the app - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis I know this principle. Maybe I just think differently, but if I explicitely set a value and this value is neither saved nor used, then it doesn't do what I explicitely wanted. Like if I tell an app to iterate 20 times, but it iterates 10 times on WIndows, 30 times on Android, 40 times on iOS, etc. That'S exactly what it does here. It uses different fonts on different platforms - which is absolutely fine if I explicitely want a default value but I explocitely don't want and the IDE doesn't let me do it. It is what it is, but thanks for the link. :)

Comment: Actually if I understood well, the thing is user defines they want X font, but since they were on Windows and it happens to be default font, then the value isn't stored. Then they run it on Android and it shows not the font they had asked for, but the default for Android. So the user wasn't expecting that (only indication is probably boldness or not in the property editor for a value that has default value and won't be stored - alternative would be to read the file that describes the form contents, but from what I remember that view is hidden in the IDE, have to open file externally to notice)

Answer (score 4):

This is by design.  A property's default value is not saved in a DFM/FMX file **unless** the property explicitly requests it via the `nodefault` or `stored=true` directive on the [property declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties) itself.  Saving default values without being asked to would bloat the DFM/FMX resource.

There is nothing you can do to override this behavior unless you derive new components to override their property declarations.

You cannot specify a different default value on a per-platform basis at design time.  There is only one property, and only one default value for it.  If you need different per-platform values at runtime, you have to either:

1. create separate per-platform Views, and assign different property values in each View.
2. set the property value in code at runtime, such as in your form's `OnCreate` event.

Comment: So to clarify it for me again: It does really mean that it is not possible to set the font `Segoe UI` on Android at design time for Android?

Comment: Then the design of RAD Studio is clearly broken.

Saving default values is unnecessary, yes. But the IDE could add an option to the object inspector to reset a value back to a default value. This would be an appropriate behaviour. Right now, the IDE forbids this, which doesn't fit to an RAD concept. The design time editor is one of the main functions. I cannot derive hundreds of components.

#1: Does not solve the problem, since it's broken design by IDE. Same behaviour with default values.

#2: Doesn't work with the linked tutorial, except you can tell me how to load fonts at runtime.

Comment: @StanE: If you think the design of RAD Studio is broken, tell Embarcadero. Complaining about it here is not appropriate, and will change absolutely nothing. Because you don't agree with the design does not make Remy's answer incorrect. He has answered the question you asked; whether you like the facts presented in the answer or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm asking and seeking for solution, not complaining. And I don't think it is broken - it IS broken. Also I have upvoted Remy's answer, so I don't understand why you imply that I though his answer is incorrect. Where did I wrote this? If this is why you guys here downvoted my question with -2, then you clearly didn't understood how the voting system works here on stackoverflow. Votes are given for content, not because you like or dislike it. Kids... Again: My question has 2 downvotes. Could someone please explain me exactly what is wrong with my initial question?

Comment: @StanE: In *your opinion* it is broken. That doesn't make it *broken*. I have no idea why your question was downvoted. I responded to your comment complaining about the design of RAD Studio. Again, complaining about it here is meaningless; StackOverflow users cannot make changes to the design of the IDE. The appropriate place to complain or express your thoughts about the functionality or design of the product is in the EMBT forums.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Simple." Well... Since you don't understand that setting this property at runtime DOES NOT WORK with the tutorial for loading custom fonts in the link I posted in my initial question and you simply keep completely ignoring this fact, then please give me a working code example, if it's that simple as you think. In short: **How to assign the font `Segoe UI` to a TLabel in a FMX app for Android?** If you can give me a working answer to this, then I will be fine.

Comment: The `TFont.FamilyName` property is not saved in the DFM/FMX file if its design-time value matches `TPlatform.GetDefaultFontFamilyName`.  Each platform has a different `TPlatform` implementation, where `Segoe UI` is the default only on Windows Vista and later. You would expect each target platform added to the project to use a different `TPlatform` implementation at design-time, but that is probably not the case since the IDE itself runs only on Windows. To use `Segoe UI` on non-Windows platforms, compile the project on XP (where the default is `Tahoma`), or set the font in code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A third solution for your problems might be to use styles for defining default font for your components. This way the font is not defined by DFM but by the style itself.

Sure if you haven't used styles before starting with them might be a bit difficult. But once you get a hang of it you will see the big advantage that styles can provide especially in project with lots of forms as you only need to change the style and the changes affect every component that uses that specific style.

Speaking of styles are you sure you aren't using them already and the style might be overriding your font settings which might explain why suggestions from others didn't work?